# Unable to deploy metadata from Partner Developer scratch org because of extra fields

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata-api, isv, scratch-org, partner

As I hoped for higher limits I created my scratch org as a "Partner Developer" org.

```
{
  "orgName":"myns",
  "edition":"Partner Developer",
  "features":[
    "CascadeDelete",
    "DebugApex",
    "AuthorApex",
    "Communities"
  ],
  "settings":{

    "orgPreferenceSettings":{
        "networksEnabled":true,
        "s1DesktopEnabled":true,
        "chatterEnabled":true,
        "translation": true
    }
  }
}
```

But now I am unable to push into my QA and Packaging org as they miss certain fields:

> sfdx-source/ns/main/default/objects/Account/fields/NameLocal.field-meta.xml
>   Could not resolve standard field's name. (161:13)
>   sfdx-source/ns/main/default/objects/Contact/fields/FirstNameLocal.field-meta.xml
>   Could not resolve standard field's name. (162:13)
>   sfdx-source/ns/main/default/objects/Contact/fields/LastNameLocal.field-meta.xml
>   Could not resolve standard field's name. (188:13)

I thought "Easy, I just rebuild my scratch org as a regular Developer org and then retry. But No! Now I am not even able to push my source into a scratch org.

How can I solve this without manually removing all the Partner specific metadata from my sources? I don't actually use all the Partner stuff. I just accidentally created a dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it the hard way. I manually removed all the Partner Developer specific metadata from my code:

- Fields
- App permissions
- WebLinks

and then I was able to push it into a Developer scratch org. Not so much work. But still a learning. I will not make my scratch orgs big and powerful from the beginning. Better upgrade than downsize.

Answer (score 6):

Since the error is not so clear on why this is happening , this is where one needs to see whats the actual metadata for the object that is getting deployed.

There is an environment variable in the DX CLI named **SFDX_MDAPI_TEMP_DIR** you might want to set it to a temp metadata directory so that when sfdx push command runs you see the actual metadata thats being deployed.

Enable in MAC using `export SFDX_MDAPI_TEMP_DIR=/users/myName/myDXProject/metadata` .This assumes you have myDXProject as project folder and metadata as the temporary folder.

For Windows set it as an environment variable. E.g. in Powershell (expand the ... out with your actual path):

```
PS C:\...\myDXProject\src> $env:SFDX_MDAPI_TEMP_DIR = 'C:\...\myDXProject\metadata'
```

Examining the metadata folder will tell whats going on here since it is weird.